# How do I crop a rectangle from a video, from the command-line?

Tags: shell, video, ffmpeg, crop

I'm capturing a video of a test-run on an iOS simulator, and I have an automated script to tell QuickTime to record only a rectangle of video.

This works well on the desktop displaying to the physically connected screen, but for remote desktop users, the resulting video is a garbled version of bits of the primary screen instead of the rectangle of the secondary user's view.

It's even worse for a Mac Pro running VMs: ALL users get a blank, black rectangle. This obtained for Yosemite and still obtains for ElCap.

Oddly, capturing a full screen works properly for all sessions, so I could record the whole thing, and then crop out the window I want - it doesn't move.

Is there a good command-line tool that can crop a rectangle from a (full screen) video stream? I looked at ffmpeg, but couldn't see it listed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view a 100 pixel square crop at position {x=100,y=100} :

> mplayer -vf "crop=100:100:100:100" foo.avi

Comment: This same filter can be used with ffmpeg when recording or transcoding.

Comment: Thanks, after a pile of Googling I posted the question, and then stumbled across the answer just now using ffmpeg with the same options - I came back to delete this post. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use ffmpeg to do this as well,

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter:v "crop=out_w:out_h:x:y" out.mp4
```

source: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4563/how-can-i-crop-a-video-with-ffmpeg